# Deserialization JSON string with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am helpless, I need deserialize JSON string in this format to class.

JSON string:

```
{
  "newNickInfo": {
    "2775040": {
      "idUser": 2775040,
      "nick": "minci88",
      "sefNick": "minci88",
      "sex": 2,
      "photon": "http:\/\/213.215.107.125\/fotky\/277\/50\/n_2775040.jpg?v=4",
      "photos": "http:\/\/213.215.107.125\/fotky\/277\/50\/s_2775040.jpg?v=4",
      "logged": false,
      "idChat": 0,
      "roomName": "",
      "updated": 1289670130
    }
  }
}
```

Class:

```
public class User 
{
    public string idUser { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }
    public string sefNick { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public string photon { get; set; }
    public string photos { get; set; }
    public bool logged { get; set; }
    public int idChat { get; set; }
    public string roomName { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
}
```

First problem is, class properties must be lower case, and second problem is I try many ways but I don’t know how cut json object from this json string and deserialize in class.
Any ides? Thank for any help.

One more question, what format would have c# class, if I want deserialize this json string into it.

Comment: What things have you tried, and what results have you gotten?

Answer (score 1):

looks like your JSON string is not correct. Look at this

```
string json = @"[

    {
      "newNickInfo": "2775040", 
      "idUser": "2775040",
      "nick":"minci88",
      "sefNick":"minci88",
      "sex":2,
      "photon":"http:\/\/213.215.107.125\/fotky\/277\/50\/n_2775040.jpg?v=4",
      "photos":"http:\/\/213.215.107.125\/fotky\/277\/50\/s_2775040.jpg?v=4",
      "logged":false,
      "idChat":0,
      "roomName":"",
      "updated":"1289670130"
     }
]";



public class User 
{
[JsonProperty] 
public string idUser{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string nick{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string sefNick{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string sex{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string photon{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string photos{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public bool logged{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public int idChat{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string roomName{get;set;}
[JsonProperty] 
public string updated{get;set;} 
}


List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);

User u1 = users[0];

Console.WriteLine(u1.nick);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, User>>>(theJsonString);
var theUser = deserialized["newNickInfo"]["2775040"];
```

Comment: Hi Domenic, your solution does not work. Try, I get compile error: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,User>>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: Yes, I forgot a closing `>`; try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool [Jsonclassgenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/). It could generate C# classes for the input Json string. You dont have to use the exact class generated. But you can see the format of the class and create a similar one in your project.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575445/c-sharp-class-to-parse-json-result/7996810#7996810) to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.