# C# class to parse JSON result

Tags: c#, json

How should be a c# class to deserialize the folowing JSON string:

```
{
   "data": [
  {
 "id" : "id0012",
     "comments": {
        "data": [
           {
              "id": "123",
              "from": {
                 "name": "xpto",
                 "id": "5ddd"
              },
              "message": "tttt",
              "created_time": "2010-01-07T09:16:15+0000"
           },
           {
              "id": "222",
              "from": {
                 "name": "wwwww",
                 "id": "343434"
              },
              "message": "3333",
              "created_time": "2020-07-07T09:30:12+0000"
           }
        ],
        "paging": {
           "previous": "prevlink",
           "next": "nextLink"
        }
     }
  }
```

]
}

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a lot of different JSON libraries for the .NET Framework. See the C# section at [json.org](http://json.org/) for a list of several different implementations. The best well known libraries of those probably is [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/documentation) which supports serialization, LINQ, BSON and more! For a quick start on reading JSON with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/documentation), you should have a look at [Reading and Writing JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReadingWritingJSON.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is related with this specific json string.

Comment: @user285677: So have you *tried* using Json.NET with that string? If so, what goes wrong?

Comment: The problem is I can't desirealized all the json string directly to a c# class because the "comments" is made of one dictionary with an array of messages and a paging class.

Answer (score 3):

As hangy says, you can certainly use Json.NET to parse that string. For example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace EvalTest
{
  public class Test
  {
    static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
        var json = JObject.Parse(text);

        var data = json["data"];
        Console.WriteLine((string) data[0]["id"]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you need more help, you should ask a more specific question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's almost as if the OP's asking for a class that would serialize to something like the example.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool [Jsonclassgenerator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/). It could generate C# classes for the input Json string. You dont have to use the exact class generated. But you can see the format of the class and create a similar one in your project.